# Vuforia VideoPlayback Landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm using Vuforia for create a demo app for my company. I can scan the target and playvideo based on the sample project. However that only in portrait orientation. If i try to scan the target image in device landscape mode, my camera also will rotate the object to portrait.

I check the code in:

```
VideoPlaybackViewController.mm
[vapp initAR:QCAR::GL_20 ARViewBoundsSize:viewFrame.size orientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

try change it to UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll, but not the camera only showing little on the left of my screen.

Try to change some code in 
SampleApplicationSession.m also, but no luck

```
- (void) prepareAR  {
// Tell QCAR we've created a drawing surface
QCAR::onSurfaceCreated();


// Frames from the camera are always landscape, no matter what the
// orientation of the device.  Tell QCAR to rotate the video background (and
// the projection matrix it provides to us for rendering our augmentation)
// by the proper angle in order to match the EAGLView orientation
if (self.mARViewOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{
    QCAR::onSurfaceChanged(self.mARViewBoundsSize.width, self.mARViewBoundsSize.height);
    QCAR::setRotation(QCAR::ROTATE_IOS_90);

    self.mIsActivityInPortraitMode = YES;
}
....cut
```

I cut the other if function since the debug always run this function.
Anybody have the same experience?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I changed the line of code in VideoPlaybackViewController.mm to

```
[vapp initAR:QCAR::GL_20 ARViewBoundsSize:viewFrame.size orientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

Since my app only work in landscape mode, so this works for me.